# deparse expressions containing `:=`?

Tags: r, parsing, colon-equals

Expressions containing `:=` don't `deparse` nicely :

```
call1 <- quote(f(a = b(c = d)))
call2 <- quote(f(a := b(c := d)))

# nice
deparse(call1)
#> [1] "f(a = b(c = d))"

# not nice
deparse(call2)
# [1] "f(`:=`(a, b(`:=`(c, d))))"
```

I would like to get the following output from `call2` : `"f(a := b(c := d))"`.

I'm looking for a general solution that deparses `:=` just like `=` or `<-` in all situations.

---

***A workaround***

This workaround uses the fact that `<<-` has similar or same precedence and is not often used. I substitute `:=` by `<<-` in the original call, then it deparses nicely, and I `gsub` it back to `:=`. I would like a clean and general solution though.

```
gsub("<<-",":=", deparse(do.call(
  substitute, list(call2, list(`:=` = quote(`<<-`))))))
#> [1] "f(a := b(c := d))"
```

Comment: May I ask (out of curiosity) what the application is?

Comment: it's to log operations, for debugging or for demos, try this : ```':=' <- `<-`; showcase <- function(x, msg = NULL){if (!is.null(msg)) message(msg);  call_chr <- rlang::expr_deparse(substitute(x)); cat("> ", call_chr,"\n"); print(x)}; showcase(cars_head := head(cars,2), "display head of cars")```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve your desired result using `rlang::expr_deparse()` which offers some printing improvements.

```
rlang::expr_deparse(call2)

[1] "f(a := b(c := d))"
```

Comment: This solution serves me well and expr_deparse also shows nicely the question mark operator. However in my benchmark expr_deparse is around 300 times slower than base::deparse, so I'm welcoming any alternative using base R